Zabbix Email notification has not been sent
I have a question,
I have added 1 host 3 hours ago to my zabbix server, which is getting low on free disk space, so 10 minutes later the alert triggered and the alert it's completely visible on the dashboard.
2 hours ago I configured an email notification rule because I want the previous event to be notified to me via email but it did not work.
Is there any way to configure it in order to send me an email notification of an alert that appeared before configuring the email notification rule? Do I have to erase the host and add it again on my Zabbix or something like that?
Thank you in advanced
I tried the following:
-Disabling and enabling the trigger which I want to be notified to me again. -Disabling and enabling the which is getting low on disk space.
But despite of all of these actions I did not get the email notification I expected and the alert is still there

You could define a temporary action (in Alerts --> Actions). The idea is to send an hourly EMail for all interesting events (to your account only), and to disable the action again after 1h.
See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/notifications/action/escalations
